# QML: An unexpected spacing

Tags: android, c++, qt, menu, qml

I am trying to create a menu bar in Qt 6.5 and QML. But I faced with problem. Why mainButton Button have a very big space from top of menuHeader Reactangle? I want just attach this Button to bottom of menuHeader Rectangle. What is the problem with this?

Code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    ColumnLayout {
        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text: "Menu"
                onClicked: drawer.open()
            }
        }
    }

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: 0.66 * parent.width
        height: parent.height

        ColumnLayout {
            spacing: 0
            anchors.fill: parent

            Rectangle {
                id: menuHeader
                width: drawer.width
                color: "red"
                height: parent.height * 0.2
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                Text {
                    text:"Some header text"
                }
            }

            Button {
                id: mainButton
                width: 50
                height: 30
                text: "mainpage"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need just to add `anchors.bottom: parent.bottom` in mainButton.

Answer (score 0):

There are several posibilities. I would go for another stacked ColumnLayout. Here an example. I have added a Repeater, because in the end the main button will not be the only one in the Drawer, I guess.

```
Drawer {
    id: drawer
    width: 0.66 * parent.width
    height: parent.height

    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 0
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: menuHeader
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: text.height
            color: "red"

            Text {
                id: text
                text:"Some header text"
                font.pixelSize: 32
            }
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            Repeater {
                model: 3
                Button {
                    id: mainButton
                    text: "button" + model.index
                }
            }

            // spacer item to push buttons up
            Item {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```